# In mono for android on c# Resource.id dose not exist why?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Speech.Tts;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace SayItAndroid{ [Activity (Label = "SayItAndroid", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class Activity1 : Activity, TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener
{
    int count = 1;
    TextToSpeech mTts;
    public void OnInit (int status)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Listening to text to speech");
    }
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);// Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.SetAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ActionCheckTtsData);
        StartActivityForResult(checkIntent, 100);           // Get our button from the layout resource,         // and attach an event to it            
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            string myText1 = "Did you sleep well?";
            string myText2 = "I hope so, because it's time to wake up.";
            mTts.Speak(myText1, QueueMode.Add, new Dictionary<string, string>());
            mTts.Speak(myText2, QueueMode.Flush, new Dictionary<string, string>());
        };
    }
    protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 100)
        {
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        }
    }
}}
```

But on the two places i have Resource im getting red line error under the Resource:

Error   1   The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context

How can i solve it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The reason that Resource cannot be found is 9 out of 10 times because the Resource is not in the same namespace as the file you are referring it from.

As stated [on this page](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/recipes/General/Projects/Specify_Default_Namespace) by Xamarin, the project's default namespace is used to store the generated Resource class file in.

If your class resides in another namespace things break.

Hope that clears things up for you.